# iOS Animation jumps to endstate in specific XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, xib, abort

I tried to find a solution for it for a while now.

I have a XIB called CameraViewController.xib. I have a few animations in it. (Alpha, Scale, Transition) I use AutoLayout and Interface Builder, xCode 6 and Objective C. (iPhone)

Every animation worked fine until 2 weeks ago they just stopped working. I can´t figure out why. Every animation is ignored and jumps directly to endstate.

It´s just in this XIB in all other XIBs and my Storyboards ViewControllers every animation is working fine.

There is no Error. I tried all possible forms of animating down to CoreAnimations but they all jump to endstate.

The XIB is complex and it has a lot of code in it. I don´t want to build the XIB again trying and trying until I find the mistake.

Anybody got the same problem or an idea ? Or a link for me where I can find out why animations aborting and jumping ?

This is driving me crazy...

EDIT :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{
                             liveLabel.alpha = 0.7;
                             liveRedDot.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             nil;
                         }];

CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
morph.fromValue = @0;
morph.toValue = @37.5;
morph.duration = 0.5;
[playStopButton.layer addAnimation:morph forKey:@"morph"];
```

I also tried different code snippets for the same animation but not a single one is working. As I said same code is working in other XIBs or ViewControllers of my StoryBoard :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6,0.6);
    playStopButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x000000,0.3);
}];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6,0.6);
    playStopButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x000000,0.3);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView
 animateWithDuration:0.5
 delay:0.0
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
 animations:^{
     playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);
 }
 completion:nil];
```

Comment: Show the animation code please

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that there's an immediate change to animated properties after you launch your animation. Dropping to Core Animation level should solve this. Or you can add KVO to these properties to see if it's true. I would also suggest using only one animation mechanism (UIView, CA) during one animation group to clear things out.